# Parsing JSON from Ansible

Tags: json, parsing, ansible

I'm looking on the web but I'm unable to find a solution, the scenario in quite complex.
I have one json array with values like these:

```
[
  {
      "IP1": "1.2.3.4"
      "IP1_VLAN": "900 - CLOUD-DEV"
      "IP1_Role": "Management"
      "IP2": "4.5.6.7"
      "IP2_VLAN": "901 - CLOUD-DEV"
      "IP2_Role": "Production"
      "IP2": "8.9.10.11"
      "IP2_VLAN": "902 - CLOUD-DEV"
      "IP2_Role": "Backup"
  }
]
```

My goal is: "Select the IP with the role of Management and tell me the address", it should select `IP*_Role == Management` and tell me in this case `1.2.3.4`

Do you have any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: Are you in charge of producing the data or do you have to do with what you get ? Because 1) it is not valid json so this is going to hard to parse 2) the structure would be much easier to search with some slight modifications.

Comment: Hello, I asked to change the JSON file, now it's a bit different, thank you for your tip!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment, my 2 cent answer: searching through your actual data structure is going to be hard and ugly. If you have the option to change it a bit, things can get much easier.

Here is an example using a list declared in yaml in the following demo playbook. Data is extracted using [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) with the relevent [`jmespath`](http://jmespath.org/examples.html) expression (i.e. the `query` variable in the debug task)

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    my_ips:
      - ip: "1.2.3.4"
        vlan: "900 - CLOUD-DEV"
        role: "Management"
      - ip: "4.5.6.7"
        vlan: "901 - CLOUD-DEV"
        role: "Production"
      - ip: "8.9.10.11"
        vlan: "902 - CLOUD-DEV"
        role: "Backup"

  tasks:
    - name: Get ips per role
      vars:
        query: >-
          [?role=='{{ item }}']
      debug:
        msg: "List of ips for role {{ item }}: {{ my_ips | json_query(query) }}"
      loop:
        - Management
        - Production
        - Backup
```

Which gives

```sh
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Get ips per role] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 23 October 2019  16:14:23 +0200 (0:00:00.043)       0:00:00.043 ***** 
ok: [localhost] => (item=Management) => {
    "msg": "List of ips for role Management: [{'ip': '1.2.3.4', 'vlan': '900 - CLOUD-DEV', 'role': 'Management'}]"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Production) => {
    "msg": "List of ips for role Production: [{'ip': '4.5.6.7', 'vlan': '901 - CLOUD-DEV', 'role': 'Production'}]"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Backup) => {
    "msg": "List of ips for role Backup: [{'ip': '8.9.10.11', 'vlan': '902 - CLOUD-DEV', 'role': 'Backup'}]"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The equivalent variable declaration in plain json would be:

```
[
  {
    "ip": "1.2.3.4",
    "vlan": "900 - CLOUD-DEV",
    "role": "Management"
  },
  {
    "ip": "4.5.6.7",
    "vlan": "901 - CLOUD-DEV",
    "role": "Production"
  },
  {
    "ip": "8.9.10.11",
    "vlan": "902 - CLOUD-DEV",
    "role": "Backup"
  }
]
```

If you have to load this from an external string (e.g. loading a file...), you can use the [`from_json` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) in your playbook

Comment: Thank you for your time man, I asked to change the json, now it's similar on what u wrote. I'm still fighting with json_query, but for now thank you!!